# Real analysis: Continuity and discontinuity

Tags: real-analysis

(Stephen Abbott. Understanding Analysis. pp 114 Question 1.3.6) The question reads

> For the following choice of $A$, construct a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that has discontinuities at every point $x$ in $A$ and is continuous on the complement of $A$.
>   Let $A = \{ x \ :\ 0 < x < 1\}$.

My function is 
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
10 &\text{if $x \in (0,1)$ and rational,} \\
20 &\text{if $x \in (0,1)$ and irrational, and} \\
10 &\text{elsewhere.} \\
\end{cases}$$

By the way, this is a piecewise function.
Does this example work?

Also for $A = \{1/n: \text{$n \in \mathbb{N}$}\}$, does the function
$$f(n) =
\begin{cases}
1/n, &\text{if n is natural number, and} \\
0, &\text{elsewhere.} \\
\end{cases}$$
work?

Comment: Your first example is *not* continuous at $0$ or $1$. Did you mean that the function is to be continuous on the complement, or that the *restriction* of the function to the complement is to be continuous?

Comment: Why not when x = 0 and x = 1, f(x) = 10 and f(x) = 10 is for anywhere other than (0,1)

Comment: Yes, that's why I ask whether you ask about a function, or about its restriction. The restriction of your example is continuous, but not the example itself.

Comment: I do not see the difference between restriction of my example and the function I provide as a example

Comment: The restriction is constant, so continuous. Your function, however, takes the value $20$ arbitrarily close to $0$, but not at $0$ itself.

Comment: I am a little confused here first of all does the function that I provide work for the question: if not is it because the constant I pick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your example works. Let's verify, backwards.

- Is your function continuous on the complement of $(0,1)$? Yes, a constant function is continuous. EDIT: As brought up in the comments, you have to be careful at the points 0 and 1.
- Is your function discontinuous at every point in $(0,1)$? Well, can you find a point in the interval at which it is continuous? (The answer will be no).

For your second question, $f(n)$ does not meet the requirements for your conditions on the reals. If you are amending the question to work on $\mathbb{N}$, then you need to pick a metric.

Comment: What do you mean for your response on my second question?

Comment: Your original question looks for a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. If you have $f(n) = 1/n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $0$ elsewhere, then $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in (0,1)$. This is continuous in the open domain. However, it might relevant to ask about continuity on functions, say, $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q}$. In such a case, we need to define what our metric is in order to determine continuity.

Comment: I am a little confused here too...do you mean the function I provide does not answer the question?

Comment: The first does. I will leave it to you to prove it, but it is sufficient. The second function does not, for all the reasons I just mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

The second example you give does not work as written. Rather, define $f$ by saying that $f(x)=0$ unless $x=1/n$ for some $n$, in which case $f(x)=f(1/n)=1/n$. (I suspect this is actually what you meant to write.) This function is discontinuous at each $1/n$, having a jump discontinuity there. It is continuous at every other point: This is clear if the point is not $0$, since then there is a neighborhood around the point where $f$ is constantly zero. But $f$ is also continuous at $0$, since $f(1/n)=1/n\to0$. Formally: Given $\epsilon>0$, let $N$ be such that $1/N<\epsilon$. If $0<|x|<1/N$, then either $x$ is not a $1/n$, and $f(x)=0$, or $x=1/n$ for some $n$, which necessarily is strictly larger than $N$, so $f(x)=1/n<1/N<\epsilon$. In either case, $|f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon$, so the definition of continuity at zero is satisfied.

Let's examine your first example. First of all, your function is discontinuous at each point $x$ of $[0,1]$ (including $0$ and $1$), since arbitrarily close to $x$ there are points $t$ with $f(t)=20$ and points $s$ with $f(s)=10$, so no matter whether $f(x)=10$ or $f(x)=20$, $f$ is discontinuous at $x$. Whether the example works, however, depends the precise meaning of "$f$ is continuous on the complement of $A$". If by this you mean that the *restriction* of $f$ to the complement of $A$ is continuous, then yes, the function you suggest is continuous there, since it is constant. On the other hand, the common meaning of the term is that $f$ is continuous at $x$ for any $x\notin A$. Under this common meaning, $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R\setminus[0,1]$, since for each $x$ outside of $[0,1]$, there is a whole neighborhood where $ f$ is constant. On the other hand, $f$ is discontinuous at $0$ and at $1$, and neither point is in $A=(0,1)$.

The example cannot be fixed by changing the values of the constants. We actually need to change the definition a bit. One suggestion is to have $f(x)=10$ for $x$ outside of $(0,1)$, or inside $(0,1)$ and rational, and to define $f(x)$ for $x$ inside $(0,1)$ and irrational in a way that $f(x)$ approaches $10$ both at $0$ and $1$, and yet is discontinuous on $(0,1)$. I suggest you let $f(x)=20x+10$ for $x$ irrational and $0<x<1/2$, and $f(x)=30-20x$ for $x$ irrational and $1/2<x<1$. This is similar to your suggestion, but rather than having the function constant on the irrationals, I picked a value on the irrationals that is away from $10$ (so we still have discontinuity at every point of $(0,1)$, but approaches $10$ at both end-points (thus ensuring continuity at both $0$ and $1$).

Comment: What does the elsewhere component and what does the irrational and (0, 1/2) goes and rational and (1/2, 1) goes ? Also, do not we need to include x = 1/2?

Comment: $x=1/2$ is rational; I am defining $f(x)=10$ if $x$ is rational. More precisely: If $x\le 0$ or $x\ge 1$, $f(x)=10$. If $0<x<1$ and $x$ is rational, then also $f(x)=10$. If $0<x<1/2$ and $x$ is irrational, then $f(x)=20x+10$. Finally, if $1/2<x<1$ and $x$ is irrational, then $f(x)=30-20x$.

Comment: Thank you so much....thank you for helping me to figure this out

Comment: You are welcome. Glad I could help.

Comment: Also for you comment on my second example could you rephrase what you wrote above since I do not quite get it

Comment: Your function should be defined as $f(1/n)=1/n$ and $f(x)=0$ for all other values of $x$, so for example $f(1/2)=1/2$, $f(1/3)=1/3$, and so on. The function is continuous at $0$, since the values of $f(x)$ get closer and closer to zero as $x$ approaches $0$. The function is continuous at all other $x$ that are not of the form $1/n$, because $f$ is constant near $x$. But $f$ is discontinuous at all $1/n$ (because there is a jump).

Comment: To clarify your point, in my original example, it does not work because 0 is not continuous. The reason my example is not continuous at 0 is when n approaches infinity, some terms closer to infinity will become zero but they should not be. Do I understand it correctly? But if I change it to f(1/n) = 1/n. This problem is solved?

Comment: In your original example, $f(1/n)=0$ for all $n>1$, so $f$ is continuous there, but that is the opposite of what the example had to accomplish. Also, in your example, $f(n)=1/n$, so $f$ was discontinuous at all positive integers. Except for $n=1$, this is the opposite of what was needed.

Comment: $$f(1/x)=
\begin{cases}
x, &\text{if x is natural number, and} \\
0, &\text{elsewhere.} \\ 
\end{cases}$$ should work right?

Comment: This version is better, but does not work at $0$.

Comment: Could I use a piece wise function to achieve those conditions?

Comment: Sure.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: $$f(n) =
\begin{cases}
1/n, &\text{if 1/n and n is natural number} \\
0, &\text{elsewhere.} \\
\end{cases}$$ does this work?

Answer (score 0):

Graph for $f(x)= \begin{cases} \color{green}{\text{ $20x+10$, $x$ irrational and $0<x<1/2$ }} \\ \color{magenta}{\text{ $30-20x$, $x$ irrational and } 1/2<x<1}  \end{cases}$

[image]